# Proof by contradiction involving set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Using a contradiction, prove the following:
>
> If $S\cap T = \emptyset$ and $S\cup T = T$, then $S = \emptyset$.

So far, I've written the definitions of the intersection and union, and I've assumed that $S\neq\emptyset$, but I'm not sure how to derive the contradiction.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I saw this very question here sometime in the past few days.

Comment: could you show me where you found it?

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951219/is-my-proof-by-contradiction-about-the-empty-set-correct)

Comment: @Mauro: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $S\neq\emptyset$.  Then there has to exist at least one object $x$ that is in $S$.  Because $S$ must be a subset of $S\cup T$ (proof not included) and $S\cup T = T$, it must then be true that $x\in S\subseteq T$, and so $x\in T$.  But then what is $S\cap T$?

Answer (score 1):

Without contradiction:
$$
S=S\cap(S\cup T)=S\cap T=\emptyset
$$
The first equality follows from $S\subseteq S\cup T$.

If you really need a proof by contradiction, then the path is almost obvious: negating $S=\emptyset$ means there exists $x\in S$. Since $T=S\cup T$ and $x\in S$, we get $x\in T$. But then $x\in S\cap T$: contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $S\cup T=T$ therefore $S\subset T$. Moreover $S\cap T=\emptyset$, then $S=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $s\in S$.

Then also $s\in S\cup T=T$ so that $s\in S\cap T$.

This however contradicts that $S\cap T=\emptyset$.

We conclude that no $s$ exists with $s\in S$, or equivalently that $S=\emptyset$.